# Bidirectional connected between to C# classes

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on project (for fun) that involves simulating logic gates.  I have a Connection.cs and a Gate.cs that is the parent of other classes like Not, And, Or, etc.  In my Gate class I have an abstract method Evaluate that will end up doing the work with inputs and setting outputs.

```
public abstract class Gate : IConnectable {

    private int[] inputs;
    private int[] outputs;

    protected Gate(int inputCount, int outputCount) {
        inputs = new int[inputCount];
        outputs = new int[outputCount];
    }

    ...

    public abstract void Evaluate();
}

public class Connection {

    private IConnectable input;
    private IConnectable output;

    public Connection(IConnectable from, IConnectable to) {
        input = from;
        output = to;
    }

}
```

In the end, I am trying to figure out a concise way to have a Gate object contain references to its connections that are inputs/outputs and to have the Connections know what is on either end of the "wire".  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want some way to represent a graph. There are many ways to do that.

I would consider a design like this as a starting point:

```
interface IGate
{
  bool Value { get; }
}

class And : IGate
{
  public IGate X { get; private set; }

  public IGate Y { get; private set; }

  public bool Value
  {
    get
    {
      return X.Value && Y.Value;
    }
  }

  public And(IGate x, IGate y)
  {
    X = x;
    Y = y;
  }

}

class Input : IGate
{
  public bool Value { get; set; }

  public Input(bool value)
  {
    Value = value;
  }

}
```

An example is:

```
new And(new Input(true), new And(new Input(true), new Input(false))).Value
```

Comment: That sounds like it might work really well. I like the idea of a graph since I had planned on running a simulation of the gates similarly to recursive calls down a tree.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this

```
   public class Node {

        private static List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
        private List<Node> inputs { get; set;}
        private List<Node> outputs {get;set;}

        protected Node() { }
        protected Node(Node input, Node outPut) {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            nodes.Add(newNode);
            newNode.inputs.Add(input);
            newNode.outputs.Add(output);
         }
    }
```